# Refreshing a layout not working in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-layout

I am trying to refresh a linear layout. This layout is being created dynamically from a web service. A refresh button invokes the below method:

```
private void setUpFields(ArrayList<String> jsonDataViewTypeRestore, ArrayList<String> jsonDataValueRestore) {
        ArrayList<String> jsonDataValue = jsonDataValueRestore;
        ArrayList<String> jsonDataViewType = jsonDataViewTypeRestore;
//      linearLayoutHorizontal.invalidate();
//      linearLayoutHorizontal.removeAllViews();
        linearLayoutHorizontal = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayoutHorizontal = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutHorizontal);
        linearLayoutHorizontal.requestLayout();
//      linearLayoutHorizontal.removeView(editText);
//      linearLayoutHorizontal.removeView(helloButton);
//      linearLayoutHorizontal.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataValue.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(jsonDataValue.get(i));
            if (jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("editBox")) {
                editText = new EditText(context);
//              linearLayoutHorizontal.addView(editText);
                editText.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.weight = 1.0f;
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                editText.setLayoutParams(params);
            } else if (jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("button")) {
                helloButton = new Button(context);
                linearLayoutHorizontal.addView(helloButton);
                helloButton.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("linearLayoutHorizontal.getChildCount() " + linearLayoutHorizontal.getChildCount());
    }
```

As you can see I have tried quite a few things as they're commented out. What is happening is that the linearLayoutHorizontal is retaining the editText and helloButton view. As you can see from the image below, there should be only one Hello, but there are multiple. 
[image]

Comment: You commented `removeAllViews()` method, so it is logical that new buttons appear after each invocation

Comment: I've tried it with removeAllViews(), but the views are still being retained. It is same result, no change.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            jsonDataViewType.clear();
            jsonDataValue.clear();
            linearLayoutHorizontal.removeAllViews();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading");
            dialog.show();
        }
```

I have to also clear my array lists in addition to removing all the views.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

First Declare this Globally.

```
ArrayList<String> jsonDataValue= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jsonDataViewType = new ArrayList<String> jsonDataViewType();
```

And Then Write this Code inside your methof Everytime When Your WebService is calling.

```
 if(jsonDataValue  != null && jsonDataViewType  != null)
 {
        jsonDataValue.clear();
        jsonDataViewType.clear();
 }

  jsonDataValue = jsonDataValueRestore; 
 jsonDataViewType  = jsonDataViewTypeRestore;

linearLayoutHorizontal = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutHorizontal);
linearLayoutHorizontal.removeAllViews();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataValue.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonDataValue.get(i));
    if (jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("editBox")) {
        editText = new EditText(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.weight = 1.0f;
        editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        editText.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayoutHorizontal.addView(editText);
        editText.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
    } else if (jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("button")) {
        helloButton = new Button(context);
        linearLayoutHorizontal.addView(helloButton);
        helloButton.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.